# How to bypass JavaScript redirection by getting content through PHP GET/POST

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers, file-get-contents

I try to collect domme information (NOTAM) on [this form](http://notamweb.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/Script/IHM/Bul_Aerodrome.php?AERO_Langue=FR) through PHP.

The problem is, the website uses JavaScript redirection to process the POST request 2 times (on [link 1](http://notamweb.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/Script/IHM/Com_Chargement.php?URL=Bul_Aerodrome.php) then on the form address (using POST), then redirects the user to form address again (using GET).

I used the Firefox Live HTTP Headers extension to collect the log of the requests and tried to spoof the sent headers (essentially Content-Type, Content-Length for POST, and even Accept and Referer when non-standard ones).

I'm using the PHP file_get_contents method.

Here is the code:

First request (POST)

```
<?php
// POST form fields definition
$donnees = array(
'bResultat' => 'true',
'bImpression' => '',
'ModeAffichage' => 'COMPLET',
'AERO_Date_DATE' => date("Y").'/'.date("m").'/'.date("d"),
'AERO_Date_HEURE' => date("H").':'.((date("i")+10 >= 60) ? 60-date("i")+10 : date("i")+10),
'AERO_Langue' => 'FR',
'AERO_Duree' => '12',
'AERO_CM_REGLE' => '1',
'AERO_CM_GPS' => '2',
'AERO_CM_INFO_COMP' => '1',
'AERO_Tab_Aero[0]' => 'LFQQ',
'AERO_Tab_Aero[1]' => '',
'AERO_Tab_Aero[2]' => '',
'AERO_Tab_Aero[3]' => '',
'AERO_Tab_Aero[4]' => '',
'AERO_Tab_Aero[5]' => '',
'AERO_Tab_Aero[6]' => '',
'AERO_Tab_Aero[7]' => '',
'AERO_Tab_Aero[8]' => '',
'AERO_Tab_Aero[9]' => '',
'AERO_Tab_Aero[10]' => '',
'AERO_Tab_Aero[11]' => ''
);


// Headers encoding function definition
function http_build_headers( $headers ) {

       $headers_brut = '';

       foreach( $headers as $nom => $valeur ) {
               $headers_brut .= $nom . ': ' . $valeur . "\r\n";
       }

       return $headers_brut;
}

// Raw request content creation
$contenu = http_build_query( $donnees );
var_dump($contenu);
echo "<br/>=============<br/>";

// Headers definition
$headers = http_build_headers(
    array(
        'Referer' => 'http://notamweb.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/Script/IHM/Com_Chargement.php?URL=Bul_Aerodrome.php',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length' => strlen($contenu)
    )
);
echo strlen($contenu)."<br />=============<br/>";

// Context definition
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; fr; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13',
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => $contenu,
        'header' => $headers
    )
);

// Context creation
$contexte = stream_context_create( $options );

// Sends POST form
$retour = file_get_contents( 'http://notamweb.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/Script/IHM/Bul_Aerodrome.php?AERO_Langue=FR', false, $contexte );
```

Second request (GET) following:

```
// Headers definition
$headers = http_build_headers(
    array(
        'Accept' => 'text/css,*/*;q=0.1',
        'Referer' => 'http://notamweb.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/Script/IHM/Bul_Aerodrome.php?AERO_Langue=FR'
    )
);

// Context definition
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; fr; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13',
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => $headers
    )
);

// Context creation
$contexte = stream_context_create( $options );

// Sends GET request
$retour = file_get_contents( 'http://notamweb.aviation-civile.gouv.fr/Script/IHM/Bul_Aerodrome.php?AERO_Langue=FR', false, $contexte );

var_dump($retour);
?>
```

I thought my question was obvious: how can PHP detect and manage such JavaScript redirections? Is there a trick to bypass them? Or any other mean to achieve it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You forgot to write your question :)

Comment: PHP can't parse french to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: Php can't detect and manage JavaScript redirections **at all**.

You'll have to understand what the JavaScript does on the page, and write some Php code that 'simulates' what the JavaScript would have done (in your case kindof "guess" there's a redirection and do another `file_get_contents()`).